# Received XPC error Connection invalid for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xcode11

I recently updated my MACOS and Xcode (v 11) to latest versions. After updating, i am not able to sync server data into local DB. Web services are getting timed out once the process starts. I keep on getting the following errors

1.) System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.RunWithTimeoutWorker[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] workerTask, System.Int32 timeout, System.Action abort, System.Func`1[TResult] aborted, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts) [0x000e8] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:956 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000f] ......

2.) Received XPC error Connection invalid for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery

3.) Received XPC error Connection invalid for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery

On other hand my tester updated his Mac, Xcode and VS to latest versions just like me and on his machine everything works fine.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: I updated my VS to latest version too. Still getting same issue.

Comment: Do you have HttpContent objects that aren't disposed properly? Can you try to downgrade your Xamarin.iOS version to see if that fixes it?

Comment: @saamer: tried downgrading Xamarin.iOS and i am not able to launch Simulator itself. So again ended up upgrading to latest build. On another Mac, VS build is 8.2 and on my Mac is 8.3 . So everything is working fine on 8.2 build not on 8.3

Comment: Could u share the code before the time out

Comment: @Saamer: Sorry cannot share the code.

Comment: Hmm seems like an issue with your system's temp or cache, since your tester was able to make everything work fine with the same conditions

Comment: @saamer : thanks will look into it.

Comment: @BharatK did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @AtifKhan: Yes. are some API calls being blocked ??

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case, my API server was crashing.  Not sure why yet.